# How Would Forced Relocation Affect a Community

Tags: society, dystopia

In a dystopian setting where people are separated into a caste system of sorts, the lowest caste, know as ship-ins, gets their nickname from a peculiar treatment: **if an offense escalates to a level where authorities become involved, the offending parties are simply separated from their town, packed into trucks, and shipped to a far away town**. The national government oversees this relocation process, and the large size of the country, as well as a strict screening process, ensures that offenders lose all contact with their loved ones forever. In relocation, the destination will always be an existing town, supposedly random selected, although worse and repeat offenders are presumed to be assigned to particularly brutal settings.

Determining if someone should be shipped occurs in a number of ways.

1. **A person attracts the attention of the national government**
   Actions seen as anti-government, such as rebellion or slander, are handled directly by national authorities. National guards posted at each town regularly survey public places - bars, temples, the like - pose an intimidating pressence. These guards reserve the right to ship-off anyone they deem in sufficient wrongdoing.
2. **A person displeases a local authority**
   Individual towns assemble local governing bodies as they please, provided they pose no threat to the national body. In some, this may be a gang or reigning family, in others an individual who through bribery and extortion persuaded national guards to enforce their authority. **Local leaders are ship-ins as well.** Through their influence, they easily ship-off those who displease them or threaten their power. Oftentimes, they become corrupt.
3. **A person displeases the general public**
   One purpose of this punishment is to keep the peace within towns. If a town raises an uproar around someone, they will generally be shipped off quickly to prevent uproar.

Depending on the severity of crime, the individual offender, as well as their family and friends, may be shipped-off. If groups are shipped off, they are separated upon relocation, intending to destroy bonds which might promote rebellion. This includes parents and children, as well as babies. Relocated babies frequently perish due to malnourishment, as existing families cannot bear the additional burden of another mouth.

The government enforces this punishment frequently enough that generally all grown members of a town can be considered "non-native" and have few family bonds. Ship-ins occur monthly, usually bringing in about a dozen people. This punishment also applies in severe cases to members of a higher caste, who lose their status and become permanent ship-ins. As such, those with more bonds will as much as in their power try to avoid relocation. Those with few bonds have less motivation to, and may even purposely commit crimes to relocate to a more ideal town.

### What would be the small-scale social and cultural effects?

I can think of a few to start off with:

- Distrust of public and strangers
- Strong resent toward government
- Plundering of goods belonging to ship-offs
- Tendency toward non-specialized/transferable work (farming/sewing)
- Cultural diversity

What others can you think of? I am particularly interested in its effects on public behaviors, like finding work, marketplaces, organized religion, and socialization.

I am less interested in the stability of this government system and how sustainable it is. On purpose, it's not. **Answers should focus on individual or interpersonal behavior**, and steer away from *"The country will collapse and people will be unhappy."*

#### Additional Details:

**Relocation can be essentially arbitrary,** however limitations like transportation resources, laziness of national police force, corruption and the like typically reserve this punishment for matters that reach public concern. To avoid getting wrapped up with authorities, citizens generally avoid raising attention to petty theft and low level offenses. That said, if neighbors have a grudge against each other, one could report the other for being "a public nuisance" and likely trigger the other's relocation.

**This is one caste of several.** Higher castes receive preferential treatment, rarely experience relocation, and have access to high-level technology. Government police fall into these higher castes. Around 10%-20% of the total population falls into this lowest caste. I currently plan on 5% of this caste being relocated on a yearly basis, however I am willing to compromise on this number.

**Ship-ins have extremely limited access to technology.** Possessing electronics or sophisticated tools will attract the attention of authorities and almost certainly result in relocation. Exceptions include higher ranking members of a town, who through corruption have earned a pass from authorities.

**Government technology exceeds current technology.** Ship-ins typically travel between a town and distribution center by truck, bus, or other low-level transport. Travel between distribution centers will be via train, boat, or other mass transport.

Comment: What about common crimes and petty crimes? Do they justify ship-out?

Comment: Math isn't on your side. What if a relocated person commits an act that's requires re-relocation? However big your country is, it's not going to be nearly big enough to afford all the relocations if you want to keep the 'they lose contact with friend/family forever'.

Comment: What kind of communications and transportation do they have access to? Neither of my parents lived in the same state as any of their parents or siblings for 30 years, and they still kept in touch perfectly well.

Comment: Have you tried to do some research? It's not as if Russia and China did not practice long-distance relocation / exile, or that it is hard to find out about the practice. Being exiled to Siberia was a real thing for centuries. For all we know, it may still be a thing. Even comrade Vladimir Ilyich Ulyanov had the pleasure; hint: his nickname Lenin comes from Lena, a river in Siberia... The Chinese practiced mass relocation to the border colonies "ten thousand [li](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_(unit)) away" for about a full millennium. And we do not do open-ended lists in the first place.

Comment: @Alexander in theory, any reason can be deemed sufficient for a ship-out, although in practice petty crimes which don't attract official attention tend to slip through.

Comment: @Sach, I agree with your statement, and a key part of my story involves a meeting of seperated persons. However, the spread between towns and the resources of the government are such that it is unlikely that you'll meet any such person again.

Comment: @Cadence ship-ins are the poorest caste and have next to no access to electronics or vehicles. Most transportation is owned by national goverment officials and possibly well off authorities.

Comment: @Groger what is "official attention"? In real life, petty criminals are caught by police (official organization) and sentenced by a court (also an official organization). In your world, "official" is some kind of secret police or political body?

Comment: @Alexander I'm specifically referring to government guards (a national police force if you will) but anything that would provoke a local leader personally would also fall under this category.

Comment: @Groger I'm trying to get an idea what % of population would end up as "ship-outs".

Comment: @AlexP I've looked around at some real world examples, but unlike this situation, most tend to be involve exile to one general location, even if separated by age/gender/sexuality. Also, this nation is less concerned about continued oppression/monitoring of citizens following relocation.

Comment: @Alexander about 5% of people will be shipped-out each year. Diligent citizens can remain in one location for decades, but it is unlikely they will spend their entire life in one place.

Comment: Siberia is indeed "one general location", but it is a *very large* general location. It's larger than the entire United States and European Union combined.

Comment: @Groger there's a serious contradiction between the expectation of 5% shipped out every year and almost all people being shipped out sometimes over their life, and all the description of ship-outs as a punishment for offenses. There are not nearly *that* many offenses and offenders even in totally arbitrary systems e.g. post-revolution red terror in early USSR. If you do have 5% punished per annum and 80+% punished in their life, then almost everyone in that community will have been shipped out for no reason at all without committing any offense, and will know that it also applies for others.

Comment: I think you're going to run into a massive [agent problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal%E2%80%93agent_problem). Your government is moving massive numbers of people - that means huge infrastructure and personnel requirements. And unlike "deport them all to Siberia" where a passenger going the wrong way is a huge red flag, here everyone is moving in different directions. It's practically tailor-made for graft and black marketeering.

Comment: @Peteris I'm not sure where you're seeing the contradiction. With 5% shipped-off each year, you have a 95% change of remaining. With about 70 years of life expectancy, you have about a (1-95%)^70 = 3% chance of remaining in one place your whole life. The arbitrary nature of it all is part of the idea, knowing that the government is against them, but without the resources to act out.

Comment: @Groger the contradiction is that everything you describe (arbitrary, exaggerated punishments for even the smallest imagined offenses) is consistent with much, much, much less than 5% p.a. - perhaps 0.5% p.a.  All the arbitrariness of the worst of the early USSR regime resulted in 5-10% people "handled" by the gulag system over multiple decades. The Nazi logistics system of transporting people to concentration camps for Holocaust wasn't able to handle 5% of population per annum, it took them many years for less than that, and not because they didn't try.  Sustained 5% p.a. is not plausible.

Comment: Seems like a counter productive measure. A repeat offender has nothing to lose after the first relocation. So, there is little to incentivise them to stop being a nuisance. Moreover, if repeat offenders are shipped to more brutal locations, then they have even more of an incentive to be disruptive, so they get shipped again.

Comment: What Tech Level is this? You're going to get a different set of issues if people are being shipped off in a horse drawn carriage, train, plane, teleported out...

Comment: @Peteris I see what you're saying, and I hadn't thought much on it. If it helps remedy this problem, this caste represents about 10%-20% of the total population of the country. Severe crimes in higher castes may receive similar punishment, but generally only ship-ins will be shipped-out. What would be a more reasonable percentage of ship-ins being relocated each year?

Answer (score 2):

A question first: Are the "criminals" simply deported to a different town, or are they deported to a worse town (environmentally or economically)?

Because in case 2, you are essentially gathering all the people who are bad for the society or government in a single place (across multiple towns of course), so there is a good chance you will end up with towns with only criminals(or 90%). Basically you have prison towns located in bad environments. It makes things easier for the government, in terms of monitoring and control as well as extermination if need be. You can just nuke the whole town and be done with it. The disadvantage is, the criminals can conspire together, making the collection more threatening than a single entity. Think of it like this, you have segregated the bad apples from different baskets into one, and put the bad basket in a dark corner. That corner if ignored will become a horrible breeding ground for mold and bugs over time. Kinda like our modern day landfills in third world countries.

In case 1, since you are essentially redistributing the criminals, that's just giving them a second chance at improving how they go about their crimes. And motivating all of them to become anti establishment by taking away their families from them. So a thief, will now not only steal money and probably not get caught due to experience, the thief and his family will try to destabilize the government secretly in two locations. That's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: This scenario falls under case 1. The destabilization and increase in skilled crime are both desirable from a plot standpoint. Thanks for your input; I am particularly interested in life on the micro (day to day/person to person) level.

Answer (score -1):

Your community would suck and people would try to leave. Eventually it would collapse.

As mentioned in the comments, just look at the history of totalitarian states like the USSR who practiced forced relocation.

The USSR built a wall to prevent people from running away.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the USSR building a wall. I know that East Germany built [a wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall), and they were closely allied with the USSR, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: This answer focuses on the macro scale and involves what I am already aware of and intend with this scenario. Focus your answer on personal or cultural behavior.